# Not Found error when using googleapis calendar.calendarList.insert

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have this function that I call from a cloud function which should create a new calendar under service account.

It just gets invoked in a promise and email is passed as ID parameter.

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const auth =  require('./getAuth')();
const calendar = google.calendar('v3');

module.exports = function createCalendar( id) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    const authClient = auth.getClient();
    calendar.calendarList.insert(
      {
        auth: authClient,
        resource: {
          id,
        },
      },
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error creating calendar', err);
          reject(err);
        } else {
          console.info('Successfully created calendar', res.data);
          resolve(res.data);
        }
      }
    );
  });
}
```

It results in error like below:

```
{ Error: Not Found
    at Gaxios.request (/srv/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:70:23)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
  response: 
   { config: 
      { url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?id=wew%40wew.com',
        method: 'POST',
        paramsSerializer: [Function],
        data: [Object],
        headers: [Object],
        params: [Object],
        validateStatus: [Function],
        retry: true,
        body: '{"id":"jdynsy@vananaz.com"}',
        responseType: 'json',
        retryConfig: [Object] },
     data: { error: [Object] },
     headers: 
      { 'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39"',
        'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
        connection: 'close',
        'content-encoding': 'gzip',
        'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        date: 'Mon, 22 Jul 2019 10:44:33 GMT',
        expires: 'Mon, 22 Jul 2019 10:44:33 GMT',
        server: 'GSE',
        'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
        vary: 'Origin, X-Origin',
        'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
        'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
        'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block' },
     status: 404,
     statusText: 'Not Found' },
  config: 
   { url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList?id=wew%40wew.com',
     method: 'POST',
     paramsSerializer: [Function],
     data: { id: 'wew@wew.com' },
     headers: 
      { ////},
     validateStatus: [Function],
     retry: true,
     body: '{"id":"wew@wew.com"}',
     responseType: 'json',
     retryConfig: 
      { currentRetryAttempt: 0,
        retry: 3,
        retryDelay: 100,
        httpMethodsToRetry: [Array],
        noResponseRetries: 2,
        statusCodesToRetry: [Array] } },
  code: 404,
  errors: 
   [ { domain: 'global', reason: 'notFound', message: 'Not Found' } ] }
```

I can't find any good documentation on the usage of the calendarList.insert anywhere, I hope someone could point me where did I went wrong in my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this :

```
const calendar = google.calendar({version:"v3"}).calendarList.insert({
      auth,
      requestBody:{
        id:"dffdsfsd"
      }

    })
```

this is from [googleapi for node](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/src/apis/calendar/v3.ts) package

Comment: are you using impersonation mode for authentication ?

Comment: what is impersonation mode?

Comment: https://medium.com/google-cloud/impersonating-users-with-google-cloud-platform-service-accounts-ba762db09092

Answer (score 0):

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
```

take out the () at the end, auth should be the default module exported from 'getAuth' file.

```
const auth =  require('./getAuth');
const calendar = google.calendar('v3');
```

I re-wrote the code below in async await because Promises can get very nested if you have multiple promises going on.

Is id passed in an object? id needs to be an object for the calendar to insert as resource. Parameters for calendarList.insert() are slightly different than events.insert().

```
module.exports = async function createCalendar(id) {
  try {
    const authClient = auth.getClient();
    const res = await calendar.calendarList.insert({ auth: authClient, resource: id })
    // insert returns an object that has a data property that includes the event you inserted
    console.info('Successfully created calendar', res.data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error creating calendar', err)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This line, did you try to take out the () at the end?

```
const auth =  require('./getAuth')();
```